# Spark select top values in RDD

Tags: python, apache-spark, rdd

The original dataset is:

```
# (numbersofrating,title,avg_rating)
newRDD =[(3,'monster',4),(4,'minions 3D',5),....]
```

I want to select top N avg_ratings in newRDD.I use the following code,it has an error.

```
selectnewRDD = (newRDD.map(x, key =lambda x: x[2]).sortBy(......))

TypeError: map() takes no keyword arguments
```

The expected data should be:

```
# (numbersofrating,title,avg_rating)
selectnewRDD =[(4,'minions 3D',5),(3,'monster',4)....]
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use either `top` or `takeOrdered` with `key` argument:

```
newRDD.top(2, key=lambda x: x[2])
```

or

```
newRDD.takeOrdered(2, key=lambda x: -x[2])
```

Note that `top` is taking elements in descending order and `takeOrdered` in ascending so `key` function is different in both cases.

Comment: when I print newRDD.top(2, key=lambda x: x[2]).take(1) there is an error:AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'take'

Comment: Well, error message says pretty much everything. `top` and `takeIOrdered` are actions and collect the data for you. It means output is a local data structure not a RDD.

Comment: Is it possible to do the same thing with an RDD, but retaining an RDD?

Comment: Any way to do this in scala as well ? This is only for pyspark it seems

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried using [`top`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.1.1/api/python/pyspark.rdd.RDD-class.html#top)?  Given that you want the top avg ratings (and it is the third item in the tuple), you'll need to assign it to the key using a `lambda` function.

```
# items = (number_of_ratings, title, avg_rating)
newRDD = sc.parallelize([(3, 'monster', 4), (4, 'minions 3D', 5)])
top_n = 10
>>> newRDD.top(top_n, key=lambda items: items[2])
[(4, 'minions 3D', 5), (3, 'monster', 4)]
```

Comment: `top` is a good choice here but you'll have to add `key` function.

Comment: Yes, of course you are correct.  My fast and dirty got the expected result, but only because the dataset was small.

Comment: If I want to get sorted avg ratings first,what should I do?

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question. Your data is in tuple triplets of 1) number of ratings, 2) title and 3) avg rating.  When you say 'get sorted avg ratings first', do you mean changing the order of the triplets or the results returned from top (which currently sorts them my avg rating from highest to lowest).

Comment: I mean do not consider selecting top N tuples.Just sort this RDD by avg ratings

Comment: newRDD.sortBy(lambda items: items[2], ascending=False). Or set top_n to 1e100....