# How to sort the RDD and get top N elements using scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have RDD of a case class(TopNModel) and want to get top N elements from giving RDD where sort by tx + rx.
In case of two equal (tx + rx) sort by mac.

```
case class TopNModel(mac: Long, tx: Int, rx: Int)
```

For example:

```
RDD[TopNModel(10L, 200, 100), TopNModel(12L, 100, 100), TopNModel(1L, 200, 400), TopNModel(11L, 100, 200)]
```

sort by tx + rx and mac:

```
RDD[TopNModel(1L, 200, 400), TopNModel(10L, 200, 100), TopNModel(11L, 100, 200), TopNModel(12L, 100, 100)]
```

My Question:

1. How to sort if rx + tx values are the same then sort based on mac?

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**: per important comment below, if indeed the requirement is to "get top N" entities based on this order, `sortBy` is wasteful compared to `takeOrdered`. Use the second solution ("alternative") with `takeOrdered`.

---

You can use the fact that *tuples* are naturally-ordered from "leftmost" argument to right, and create a tuple with the negative value of `tx + rx` (so that these are sorted in decending order) and the positive value of `mac`:

```
val result = rdd.sortBy { case TopNModel(mac, tx, rx) => (-(tx + rx), mac) }
```

**Alternatively**, if you want `TopNModel` to *always* be sorted this way (no matter the context), you can make it an `Ordered` and implement its `compare` method. Then, sorting by identity will use that `compare` to get the same result:

```
case class TopNModel(mac: Long, tx: Int, rx: Int) extends Ordered[TopNModel] {
  import scala.math.Ordered.orderingToOrdered
  def compare(that: TopNModel): Int = (-(tx + rx), mac) compare (-(that.tx + that.rx), that.mac)
}

val result = rdd.sortBy(identity)
```

Comment: Agreed on how to order it, but don't use sortBy to just take the top N elements, see this instead: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31882221/spark-select-top-values-in-rdd

Comment: Very good point @V-Lamp - I somehow missed that. `takeOrdered` is the right approach